# Close command prompt after executing batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have this in a .bat file (windows 7):

```
taskkill /F /IM CouchPotato.exe
TIMEOUT /T 5
CouchPotato.exe
exit
```

(The couchpotato tends to crash alot.)

The command prompt stays open until the process ends.

Is there a way to close it after the process has excecuted?

I tried /silent after the .bat shortcut, but doesn't work..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run your application with `start`. This command returns immediately.

```
start CouchPotato.exe
```

See also [How do I create a Windows Batch file that does not show the Command Prompt when executed?](https://superuser.com/questions/233348/how-do-i-create-a-windows-batch-file-that-does-not-show-the-command-prompt-when)

Or, alternatively, how about not having a command prompt show at all? See [How to run a batch file without launching a "command window"?](https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window)