# How could I make a timed mute button on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, mute

I am aware of one method to put a mute button link on the desktop of windows 10, but is there a simple way to run this link twice within a time period? Would it be simple to make a script to launch the shortcut twice?

[link on how to make a desktop mute button link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-mute-the-system-volume-in-windows/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script like:

```
^!m::
Send {Volume_Mute} 
Sleep, 600000
Send {Volume_Mute} 
return
```

When you use the hotkeys: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> this script will "push the mute button" (even if you don't have a physical one), wait 10 minutes (600000 miliseconds) and then "push the button" again to unmute

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by making a bat file that utilizes the program nircmd.
A bat file could be made by using textedit, entering the following lines, and changing the file type to .bat

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\shortuts\mute.lnk
timeout /t 30 /nobreak 
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\shortuts\mute.lnk
```

The disadvantage to this is that the windows command prompt opens in front of other programs, and that this dat file cannot be moved to the shortcut bar.

[Here is a link on how to move mute to the taskbar.](http://www.howtogeek.com/66670/from-the-tips-box-pin-any-file-to-the-taskbar/)

[And here is how to run a hidden script.](https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window)

Answer (score 1):

I already did it, with the Autohotkey app, then adding the script shortcut direct to stratup folder and it work on Windows starup.
It will mute the 30 secs Spotify Anoying Ads like a muted button by presing º
(i used º as hoytkey)

º::

Send {Volume_Mute}

Sleep, 30000

Send {Volume_Mute}

return

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).