# Running a batch silently, but how can I get process ID to show a specific name?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I have followed this here to run a batch file silently, in the background and doesn't show on taskbar, it's great.

[How to run a batch file without launching a "command window"?](https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window)

The thing is, when all batch file run, all of the process ID in task manager shows the same process Name. Different `cmd.exe` and `conhost.exe` by the user, so this means if I got 5 looping batch running they'll all show `cmd.exe` and `conhost.exe` and I have no idea which is which If I wish to restart them or end them.

[image]

How to get them with specific name?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried killing wscript.exe (or cscript.exe) instead?  What happens if you do that?  One other thing you could do is use a unique command line for launching your batch and use PowerShell/WMI to lookup the process by command line.. like this.. `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'conhost.exe'" | Select-Object CommandLine`

Comment: Perhaps you should thing about "Why do I need to do this?".  Your solution to this problem probably rests with not making a batch file that loops forever and instead exits when it is done.  I hope you aren't in IT.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas with the powershell cli, it just shows conhost.exe 0x4.. 4 of them lol.  also task manager doesn't show wscript.exe id at all, maybe cause its ran from vbscript as hidden not sure.

Comment: if your using a vbs to start the script, you can use that vbs to also get it's own PID for use in identifying which cmd is a child of it for use with tasklist / taskkill.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296037/find-my-own-process-id-in-vbscript#:~:text=To%20retrieve%20the%20own%20process,that%20runs%20the%20same%20script.